# I'm asking what Blocking Records in DBMS is?

Tags: rdbms

I'm referring to file organization in DBMS. But I can't understand what is Blocking Records. If you can please explain me the term Blocking Records.

Comment: Where exactly did you see this term & how was it used? This doesn't have a common meaning, except the general one where data is typically processed in "records" & "blocks" of multiple smaller pieces. So you need to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking record is, File records divide into Blocks. A database is a collection of large amount of related data. In case of RDBMS (Relational Database Management System), the data is stored in the form of relations or tables.

when stored the data stored in tables but actually this huge amount of data is stored in the form of files in physical memory.(A File is a collection of related records stored on the secondary storage)

There are various strategies for mapping file records into blocks of disk

**1. Spanned Mapping** -: suppose when File record is too large. hence stored inside the block even if it can only be stored partially hence we stored a record of file in two blocks.

**2. Unspanned Mapping** -:  the record of a file is stored inside the block only if it can be stored completely inside it.